# How to change 1 file with the wrong extension?

Tags: files, extension

How to change 1 file with the wrong extension. It's in the /etc folder to add to the complication of a "read only" folder.
I accidentally put hosts.allow when I should have put hosts.deny from the desktop to the /etc folder.

All other answers are for changing many files extensions or whole folders but I only need to change 1.

Comment: Run `sudo -H nautilus` and there will be no "read only" problem.

Comment: @Pilot6 .. avoid running GUI stuff as root if possible. You have already founf the terminal, so doing `sudo mv /etc/hosts.allow /etc/hosts.deny` would be just as easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rename any file using `mv` command.

Run

```
sudo mv /etc/hosts.allow /etc/hosts.deny
```

and it is renamed.

`sudo` is needed for system directories.

You can also copy any file from your desktop to `/etc`.

```
sudo cp ~/Desktop/hosts.allow /etc
```

You can delete any file in `/etc` by

```
sudo rm /etc/hosts.deny
```

Your file names is for example.